# Separate sprints from versions

Tags: youtrack

We'd like to split a version into several sprints, what is the best way to do this? Currently it seems to me that sprint == versions since every sprint is used as a affected version which for me doesn't feel right. What I'd like to do is the following:

I'd like to specify a version, say 1.0.0. This version is split in several sprints, A, B, C. No if a bug after the final release occurs, i like to specify as affected version 1.0.0 and not sprint A, B or C.

Is this somehow possible?

We use the YouTrack cloud hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, usually sprint == `Fix version` (the version in which this feature/task is meant to be implemented). `Affected version` is the one that contains the given bug (this version is implemented already). These two kinds of versions can use the same set of values (standard behaviour) or the different ones (can be changed in custom fields settings).

So, your `Fix versions` set of values should contain `A`, `B` and `C`, and the `Affected versions` one should contain `1.0.0`. If you prefer using the same set of versions in both cases, you can leave sprint `1.0.0` (corresponding to `Fix version` `1.0.0`).

Now, when you create a swimlane/task on an Agile Board in a selected sprint, the corresponding version is set as a `Fix version` (e.g. when you create a task in `B` sprint, the `B` `Fix version` is set to this task).

When you create a bug on an issue list, you can set `Affected version` as `1.0.0`.

If you also want to set affected version for `Bug`s automatically, you can write simple workflow rule:

```
rule Set affected version 

when issue.becomesReported() && issue.Type == {Bug} { 
  issue.Affected versions.add({1.0.0}}); 
}
```